# How to dynamically register queues to nest js bull queue

Tags: nestjs, bull-queue

When you know the list of queues to be registered, you can add them using registerQueue() in nestjs module instantiation but how to dynamically register a queue, for eg. if I have a multi tenant architecture, when a new tenant is created I want to register a new queue dynamically, is it possible to do with nest js bull queue ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can do that with the Nest package. Check [this](https://github.com/nestjs/bull/issues/580) GitHub issue response from the Nestjs's creator.

You can, however, use the vanilla Bull package.

For example, imagine that you have a Controller like this:

```js
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(
    private queuesManager: QueuesManagerService
  ) {}

  @Post(['generate-queue'])
  generateQueue(
    @Body() generateQueueDto: GenerateQueueDto
  ): Promise<GenerateQueueResponse> {
    return this.queuesManager.generateQueue(generateQueueDto.name);
  }

  @Get(['get-all-jobs'])
  getAllJobsFromQueue(
    @Query() queryParameters: GetAllJobsEndpointQueryParameters
  ): Promise<Bull.Job[]> {
    return this.queuesManager.getAllJobsFromQueue(queryParameters.name);
  }
}
```

And the `QueuesManagerService` looks like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class QueuesManagerService {
  async generateQueue(name: string): Promise<GenerateQueueResponse> {
    const queue: Bull.Queue = new Bull(name);
    await queue.add({ test: 'test' });
    return {
      status: 200,
      message: `Queue with name ${name} generated successfully!`,
    };
  }

  async getAllJobsFromQueue(name: string): Promise<Bull.Job[]> {
    const jobStatuses: Bull.JobStatus[] = [
      'waiting',
      'delayed',
      'active',
      'completed',
      'failed',
    ];
    const queue: Bull.Queue = new Bull(name);
    const jobs: Bull.Job[] = await queue.getJobs(jobStatuses);
    return jobs;
  }
}
```

You could interact with the server using `curl`:

```
$ curl -X POST -d 'name=myFirstQueue' localhost:3333/api/generate-queue

# response
{"status":200,"message":"Queue with name myFirstQueue generated successfully!"}

###

$ curl localhost:3333/api/get-all-jobs?name=myFirstQueue

# response
[{"id":"1","name":"__default__","data":{"test":"test"},"opts":{"attempts":1,"delay":0,"timestamp":1639085434398},"progress":0,"delay":0,"timestamp":1639085434398,"attemptsMade":0,"stacktrace":[],"returnvalue":null,"finishedOn":null,"processedOn":null}]
```

**PS1**:

[Bull's Github](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull)

[queue.getJobs() reference](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/develop/REFERENCE.md#queuegetjobs)

**PS2**:

My Classes and Interfaces:

```js
export class GetAllJobsEndpointQueryParameters {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name!: string;
}

export class GenerateQueueDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name!: string;
}

export interface GenerateQueueResponse {
  status: number;
  message: string;
}
```